# Image zooming in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, image, flex4, zooming

I have a photo gallery. All the photos are displayed as thumbnails. When a user clicks on a thumbnail, the preview will be displayed in a canvas with full size. Now, I want to zoom the displayed image as much as possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you explain more? Zooming can be presented in many effects.

Comment: Hi @Shivan Raptor, I have a photo gallery. All the photos are displayed as thumbnails. When a user clicks on a thumbnail, the preview will be displayed in a canvas with full size. Now, I want to zoom the displayed image as much as possible. I need a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use the [standard Pan/Zoom component](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom.html).

Its in beta but pretty stable.

You can mix it with [something like this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/08/creating-a-simple-image-gallery-with-the-flex-tilelist-control/) to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replies. I got solution here [link](http://www.rockholla.org/technology/2011/01/07/flex-as3-pan-zoom-component)